# Hibernate - ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve data from a MySQL database through Hibernate, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[...]
```

I use a class called DAOFactory to get the hibernate session:

```
public class DAOFactory {

    private static boolean isInstance = false;  
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry; 
    private static Session session;

    private DAOFactory() throws ExceptionInInitializerError{        
        if( !isInstance ) {
            try {               
                Configuration cfg   = new Configuration().configure();              
                serviceRegistry     = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties())
                                                .buildServiceRegistry();
                sessionFactory      = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object."+ ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();         
            isInstance = true ;
        }               
    }

    public static DAOFactory getInstance() {        
        return new DAOFactory() ;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session ;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/enigma</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` is already in the classpath:

[image: classpath]

Does anyone see what I'm missing ?

Comment: Add the jar to your _runtime_ classpath

Comment: If you are working on a web application put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar under lib folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL jdbc driver and Eclipse: ClassNotFoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: I am working on a JPA project, and the 2 previous questions aren't related. But thanks @Reimeus, it was just that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to Reimeus for the answer. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` needs to be in the *runtime* classpath.

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath -> Add external JAR.

Clean everything, try again, and the Exception is gone.

Answer (score 23):

For those who use **Maven**: add the following dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

or choose another version from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

Then you can get the artifact using:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

(if you don't use the IDE).

Comment: Beware that version 6 does not support JDK 1.7 anymore (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-versions.html)

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar.` To fix this issue I changed the driver class name from

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

to

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it can be not a suitable solution to add `jar` to `classpath` via *Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath -> Add external JAR*.

**First case**

When the `jar` file cannot be put into `classpath` folder, there is alternative way to load class from the another place. You just need to instantiate [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and then invoke `loadClass()` on it (was mentioned [here](http://:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349015/loading-classes-not-present-in-the-classpath)):

```
URLClassLoader urlCL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {"path_to_jar"});
Class driverClass = urlCL.loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

**Second case**

If you would like to add your class to `classpath` at runtime (I prefer the answer of [Ranjit Aneesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385774/ranjit-aneesh) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime)), for this purpose you may create a very simple custom class loader extending [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) with the only overridden `addUrl` method:

```
public class DynamicURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public DynamicURLClassLoader(URLClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader.getURLs());
    }

    @Override
    public void addURL(URL url) {
        super.addURL(url);
    }
}
```

Then invoke it:

```
URLClassLoader urlCL = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
new DynamicURLClassLoader(urlCL).addURL("path_to_jar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue with mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar. To fix this issue I changed the driver class name from

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
to

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

- I had above dependency in Maven.
- The scope tag had caused the error.
- Removing scope tag solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar
from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.20/
Add the jar to class path

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath -> Add external JAR.