# Error while configuring hibernate with mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

i am writing my first example on hibernate .... i am getting error while configuring.... i am using netbeans.....

my hibernate.cfg.xml file
[image]

I am getting this error... i am using mysql as DB in backend
[image]

I added mysql driver in classpath , still error persist....
[image]

Comment: You probably need to register the driver first: http://netbeans6.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/registering-database-in-netbeans-ide.html

Comment: Thanks... i did the steps... i can access from IDE .. but still i am getting same error when i am trying to create Student.hbm.xml.

Comment: Probably it's the same reason, just this time you need to register the driver for the application. Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319712/hibernate-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver The hibernate.cfg.xml points to the mysql driver and it shuld be in the classpath.

Comment: Post your spring configuration files.